# Django 1.10 server to server websockets

Tags: python, django, websocket

Thanks to the huge update 1.10, Django now supports async websockets. Awesome! 
I've used the websockets to connect a client to the Django server. Now I have a use case where the server needs to initialize a socket connection to another server.

**Question:** Is it possible for a Django backend to initialize a websocket connection to another server? If yes, how can is this done?

Answer (score 1):

It is definitely possible to initialize a websocket connection from Django to a WS server. You can use a number of websocket packages such as https://websockets.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ to start a websocket client.

```
import asyncio
import websockets

async def hello():
    async with websockets.connect('ws://localhost:8765') as websocket:

        name = input("What's your name? ")
        await websocket.send(name)
        print("> {}".format(name))

        greeting = await websocket.recv()
        print("< {}".format(greeting))

asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(hello())
```

You should take care to decide where to put this code as websockets are by nature asynchronous.